Помогите, пожалуйста, найти предложение с вводным словом!
Здравствуйте всем знатокам! Проходил тест на сайте, где был такой вопрос:
«Предложение с вводным словом дано в варианте...» (варианты ответов на скриншоте)
Мой вариант ответа оказался неверным. Помогите, пожалуйста,  разобраться с вопросом, так как мои поиски в интернете не оказались успешными. Заранее спасибо за ответы!


Поможем. Найдем.
• Это предложение С:
Вспрыснутые дождем травы отдохнули, потемнели, и, может быть, поэтому в лесу было так прохладно, тихо.
• Может быть — вводное сочетание.
• Примеры
Она не любила такую погоду, когда краснеет нос, и, может быть, поэтому быстро удалилась (Эдуард Лимонов. Книга воды).
Это заставляло нервничать тех, кто вцеплялся в каждую новую карту, как в последнюю надежду, и, может быть, поэтому они и проигрывали (Евгений Евтушенко. «Волчий паспорт»).
✦ Вывод: вариант А не является верным (везде ошибки бывают!).
P. S. Предложение переделано для процесса обучения. Неправильно это.
Посмотрите, каково оно на самом деле. Красота!

Вспрыснутые дождём травы потемнели, закурчавели и пахли так густо, что ещё сильнее ударило в голову. Пьяный от счастья он жадно вбирал в себя и это необыкновенное утро, и запахи омытых цветов и трав на лугу, прибрежных ив с тёплыми птичьими гнёздами, и весь большой зелёный мир, вбирал, чтобы благодарно сохранить всё это до конца дней своих.
[Игорь Краснов. Счастливая песнь уходящего лета]

